# wait for a child when both parent and child do an exec()

Tags: c, unix, exec

I have found this interesting question (note I just started studying this, so I'm a novice on UNIX system calls, signals, etc.) which I am unable to solve so far:

Let's say that we have the following code on main.c:

```
switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        printf("error!");
        break;
    case 0: // child process
        execvp(childCommands[0], childCommands);
        break;
    default: // parent process
        execvp(parentCommands[0], parentCommands);
        break;
}
```

Would it be possible, in any way, for the original parent process to do a wait() on its child?

As far as I know, pending signals still remain pending after doing an exec(), but any defined capture functions for them do not, so I am not sure if any "signal magic" could be done here.

Comment: The original parent process is replaced by the default `execvp()`.  It cannot do anything because it doesn't exist any more.

Comment: have one process fork twice to create what you call parent and child, then you can wait for both of them

Comment: I *think* the new program in the parent process would still be able to call `wait` and receive the exit status of the child process that was created before the `exec`, but I'm not sure and I don't have time today to either close-read POSIX or try to write a test program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The _program_ running in the parent process is replaced, but the parent _process_ still exists, and I'm like 75% sure it's still considered to be the parent of the child process.

Comment: @zwol — yes, the replacement parent process could wait and get the corpse of the child.  If it created its own kids, it needs to be careful; it probably won't expect a corpse from a child it didn't create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original program running as the parent process is replaced by the new program executed by the `default` clause of the `switch`, and (assuming that the `execvp()` succeeds) that means that the original program cannot wait for its child — the original program is no longer running.

However, the replacement program has a child that it can wait for, but it is unlikely that the replacement program is aware of the presence of that child until it spots that it got the status of a child that it never created when it called one of the `wait()` family of functions.  That means that any program that forks other processes and subsequently waits for dead children should tolerate corpses from processes that it did not create; its predecessor program may have created the process that just died.

You may need to change the organization of the process tree.  For example, the original process could fork twice, and the second child would execute the command identified by the `parentCommands` array, while the original process waits for both children to die.

Alternatively, perhaps the original program can tell the replacement that the child exists somehow.  There are many ways to do that (arguments, environment variables, IPC mechanisms, …).

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and sorry for the lateness, things got in the middle!), indeed two forks on the parent or a" double-fork" (as explained by @user414777) looks like a good strategy

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no magic. The program exec'ed by the parent could of course reap the children if it's designed to do so. But if it's not, it will let them accumulate as zombies. You could set `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN` before, which should prevent children from becoming zombies, but that's not guaranteed to survive the `execve()` (1).

The thing that everybody does in window managers and such is a "double-fork" -- fork again in the child and do the execve in the grand-child, with the child immediately exiting, being waited for and reaped by its parent, and abandon the grand-child to its fate (to be adopted by init or by a "subreaper").

(1) It will on Linux but not on OpenBSD. But even if it does, the exec'ed program may have other ideas: e.g. set its own `SIGCHLD` handler and get terribly confused by the unexpected children.